# Toggle Facebook Comments Plugin color scheme

Tags: javascript, facebook

MY blog has dark color switch. I want Facebook comments to switch to dark colors too. I know how to set 'data-colorscheme' attribute to 'dark' using JS, obviously this alone wont affect the current iframe. Any suggestions?

Comment: Replace the HTML element used to embed the plugin with a new one, call `FB.XFBML.render()` afterwards to get it rendered.

Comment: Is it possible to replace the attribute only?
I tried replacing attribute then called FB.XFBML.render().
I got "Uncaught ReferenceError: FB is not defined
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous>"

Comment: Please show a proper [mre] of what you are doing.

Comment: `const facebookComment = document.querySelector('.fb-comments');
facebookComment.setAttribute("data-colorscheme", "dark");
 FB.XFBML.parse();`

Comment: I meant, how you are embedding the comment plugin in the first place.

Comment: [link](https://codepen.io/MikeMoss/pen/qBdgMoX)

Comment: Switching between dark and light mode seems to work fine there?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is a known issue (several bug reports filed) that Facebook is opting not to fix. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63557153/374689).