# Facebook Comment Plugin Darkmode Not Working

Tags: html, facebook, plugins, comments, darkmode

As the title says, I cannot get the dark mode to work for the facebook comment plugin. I used the tool on FB developers and added the "data-colorscheme="dark"" as per the instructions but it wont work, any ideas?

```html
<div 
class="fb-comments commentsdark" 
data-href="myurl" 
data-numposts="5" 
data-width="80%" 
data-colorscheme="dark">
</div>
```

It loads but in a light theme which is unreadable on my dark theme website.

Comment: I have the same problem. It used to work well few months ago, but now the plugin just ignores the data-colorscheme="dark" part.  Did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 3):

There’s already several bug reports for that.

https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/1759174414250782/

Quote (Facebook Team response from Aug 14, 2020):

> After speaking with our internal team, we unfortunately are unable to fix the issue at the moment. Our teams are currently working on improvements for the platform therefore they won't be able to fix this specific issue in the near future. Unfortunately, we now need to close this report as a Won't Fix, but we will keep tracking it internally, and we will update this bug report whenever this gets fixed.

Comment: still no answer til 2021-10-21

Answer (score 1):

While the following does not solve the dark colorscheme issue, it does allow you to colorize the buttons.  For the like FB SDK, which has a .fb-like class, use the hue-rotate filter.  Example:

```
.fb-like {
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(244deg);
    filter: hue-rotate(244deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Facebook removed support for the `data-colorscheme="dark"` and `light` they've allowed us to style the background, which is the best I could do to make the comments readable and match the general theme of a site. `#aaa` is lightgray.

```
<div style=background="#aaa">
   <div className="fb-comments" data-href={url} data-numposts="5" width="100%"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

I wass introduce block with white background

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).